# Changing timezone in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

Alright, quick question.

A server is running in Eastern Time. PHP program needs to make date calculations using Central time.

At the moment, I am putting this line at the very top of my script:

```
putenv("TZ=US/Central");
```

Is that the best way to go about that or is there some PHP trick I'm not aware of?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and all the date/time functions in the script will use it.