# how to change the default time zone in just one of my php file not config file?

Tags: php, timezone

I have to change the time zone for one of my services; so just one file not in config for all php files! How can I do that! in that file I'm using filectime but apparently it is using another time zone!

Your help is appreciated.

If you need more clarification, please let me know

ADDED:

Sorry to say that but still after  using date_default_timezone_set fro my city, my problem is not solved! I have a file the creation of which is : Nov 07 2013 7:36:50 but after using your time zone function for my city and  following code:

```
 $createTime = filectime($dirPath . '/' . $file);
```

the $creattime still it is : 2013-11-08T00:36:50Z

So it seems that time zone doe not have any effect on filectime! apart from adding hours (the difference hours) to the result of my filectime to adjust the difference, is there any other better ways?

Thanks

Comment: put the needed timezone at the top of your page, at the bottom put the original. it should work.

Comment: This has been answered [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257994/changing-timezone-in-php)

Comment: `filectime` returns an int of a UTC timestamp, so setting any time zone isn't going to do anything different for *that* function.  Instead, it will apply to date/time functions that actually *use* time zones, such as those found on the `datetime` class.  You didn't show us any of your actual code, so it's impossible to provide a real answer.  Please edit your question to show your code if you'd like a better response.

Comment: but there is no code; just a simple filectime! So I added that one in my original question! and  apart from adding hours (the difference hours) to the result of my filectime to adjust the difference, is there any other better ways?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "Changing timezone in PHP". As mentioned by Matt Johnson, `filectime()` is not affected by `date_default_timezone_set()`. Voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

You might find php's [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) helpful.

> date_default_timezone_set() sets the default timezone used by all
>   date/time functions.

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Here is a [list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

### Edit:

I overlooked the fact that you're using `filectime()`. That function returns a unix timestamp, which does not contain any timezone data. So `date_default_timezone_set()` will not affect those results.

Instead, you can "translate" a date object from the server's timezone to a different timezone in PHP like this:

```
// for testing purposes, get the timestamp of __FILE__
// replace __FILE__ with the actual file you want to test
$time_created=filectime(__FILE__);

// build date object from original timestamp
$date=new DateTime(date('r',$time_created));

// translate the date object to a new timezone
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('America/Los_Angeles'));

// output the original and translated timestamps
echo"<p>Original Timestamp: ".date('r',$time_created)."</p>";
echo"<p>Los Angeles Timestamp: ".date_format($date,'r')."</p>";
```

Here's a [working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1k0-h6x).

Comment: Sorry to say that but still my problem not solved! I have a file the creation of which is : Nov 07 2013 7:36:50 but after using your time zoe foe my city it is : 2013-11-08T00:36:50Z

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked that you were using `filectime()`. You will need to know the timezone in which the file was created in order to translate it to a new timezone, as unix timestamps contain no timezone data. Are you running your PHP code on the same server on which the file you're testing was created?

Comment: Thanks :) Yes. Running on teh same server but still the out put of filectime is different to the real time of file creation!

Comment: Updated my answer with a method to translate server timestamp from one timezone to another. I hope it helps.